# Error in  connecting to FTP: Could not connect to server

Tags: ftp

I am using Filezilla  to upload files to a server.

My host username and password is correct but it gives me this error:

> `Could not connect to server`

Please tell me what can I do?

Comment: Provide a better explanation of your issue and what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

First, check out your target FTP server with the command-line FTP client, just to see if you get an FTP login prompt.

Then figure out if your username is case sensitive.

Then figure out if need to force active or passive mode.

(check the man page for your ftp client, or type 'ftp /?')